# How much data store in Memcache

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I have used Memcache in one of my projects and I have to store around 1GB data but cannot store more than 1MB data. I have also increased limit_maxbytes = 1073741824

I have used Memcache version 2.2.7 with PHP Version 5.6.35, I have also attached my Memcache details. I need to know how much data is stored in Memcache.

Please Help.

[See the php info screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWNLr.png)

[Memcache detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHCwC.png)

Comment: i can't image why you are storing that much data in memcache

Comment: due to some big response in rest apis and project requirement as well.

Comment: i would still really consider that approach

Comment: Yes you are right but i need to find any another way to store more then 1MB store in Memcache @smith